Filtering by number of comments in GitHub Search API
I am trying to pull issues from the github tensorflow repo, that have more than 250 comments. However, I always receive 30 results (in accordance with GitHubs Pagination), when I should only receive 2 results.
Here's my code:
owner = "tensorflow"
repo = "tensorflow"
n_comments = 250
url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues"

token = "mytokenhere"

params = {
    'sort':'comments-desc',
    'q': 'comments:>{n_comments}',
}

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"token {token}",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json" # specifying json-formatted data
}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = params)

issues_with_sufficient_comments = []

if response.status_code == 200:
    # Extract the JSON data
    data = response.json()
    
    for item in data:
        issues_with_sufficient_comments.append(item['number'])
        print(item['number'])
        print(item['comments'])
    
else:
    # Print error message if request failed
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")


I also tried
url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues?q=comments:>250", which did not help either

There seems to be no filter on number of comments. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organization-issues-assigned-to-the-authenticated-user. Try pulling all issues first (all pages). Then filter in python itself by number of comments.


Tried following api call to list issues sorted by comment count. Most comments i have seen is 133.

https://api.github.com/repos/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues?sort=comments&direction=desc&per_page=100


Also i dont see any filtering parameter for number of comments.
I suggest following workflow for your usecase.

1. get all issues
2. filter by number of comments you wants (comments > n)
3. process

or
1. Use sort and direction parameter.
2. 
   -if all response issue are > n_required_comments.
      - get new page
      - repeat 2
   - else
     - filter any issue with  < n_required_comments from last api call.
     - return



Both approaches are valid second one makes lesser number of api calls for some cases.

minimal working code using second approach.


def req_issues(n_comments=50):
    ans = []
    page = 1
    while 1 == 1:
        res = req.request(
            'get',
            'https://api.github.com/repos/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues?sort=comments&direction=desc&per_page=100&page={}'.format(page),
            headers=headers)
        
        res_lst = res.json()
        filterd_lst = [x for x in res_lst if x['comments'] > n_comments]
        ans.extend(filterd_lst)
        page += 1
        
        if len(filterd_lst) != len(res_lst):
            return ans

something = req_issues(60)

